# Using c++, how do I get the value of the stack pointer in msvc X64

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 64-bit

Using c++, what is the fastest way to get either the stack pointer or a rough estimate of the maximum value of the stack pointer in msvc++ on X64?

I'm going to use it to write this INLINE function:

```
static __forceinline bool IsOnStack(const void *p) {
    return UINT_PTR(p) < __ESP;
}
```

I could use it as a macro if that is better

```
#define ISONSTACK(a)
```

thanks!

EDIT

I need to know if something is on the stack so other code won't free it.  Suffice it to say its a legacy implementation of smart pointers that I am making faster.  All I have to work with is the address of the object the smart pointer is referring to.  I am making a change so a smart pointer can refer to an item on the stack, which will eliminate superflous heap allocations.  The 64 bit stack appears to be a relatively low virtual address.  Our allocator uses a predefined virtual base address (16GB right now).  I could just assume anything below that is on the stack.  This method might accidentally assume anything allocated with malloc or ::new was on the stack, which wouldn't be the end of the world, since we aren't supposed to ever use those.  I thought I'd see if there was a better way to get an idea where the stack was.  Performance is more important than accuracy as long as we don't get false negatives.

EDIT

I know we are currently only assigning smart pointers to allocated memory because we only use 2 ways to set smart pointers:

```
new(spFoo) CFoo();  // uses an overridden new to do this
```

or

```
spFoo = spOtherFoo;
```

I am thinking of adding:

```
CFoo Foo();
spFoo = &Foo;
```

**EDIT**
I should add that we do not use std libraries (partly because the code is so old and partly because our application is an edge case and performance is so important).  I don't want to make this a debate about standard libraries, which we all agree are awesome.  I don't have that with this application.  Our code only runs on internal servers.  Our code is all 64 bit.  Sometimes we use threads, but that is rare.  Portability is not an issue.  We use microsoft visual studio 2013, which is vc++ 2012.  We run on server 2008.  We will be upgrading to server 2012 some day, and visual studio 2015 when it comes out.

This started out with the usual gripe about inline assembly not being available.  Then I was having a hard time finding documentation about the general memory layout (where the stack goes, where the heap goes, etc) of a vc++ app running on windows.

Comment: Seems like the solution to something you shouldn't need... Why do you need to know if something is on the stack? [in other words, you are probably asking an XY question]

Comment: Declare a variable on the stack and take its address. But as @MatsPetersson says you probably don't really need to know this.

Comment: I am very curious, too, as to why you would even need to do something like this? Also, I don't think this will do what you think it will do. Could you provide an example of your overall goal for this? perhaps its an xy problem, and I would rather work in x :)

Comment: Also, you've indicated 64 bit, Im assuming you're x86-64 machine then. Personally x64 only tells me it's a 64bit processor, there are many of those.

Comment: Your esample also assumes the stack is at the highest address in the virtual address-space, which of course is nothing even close to guaranteed. In other words, `int *p = new int;` could well give a `p` that is true with `UINT_PTR(p) <  __ESP` - because `p` is at a higher address than `__ESP` - even more so if you start using threads, as the stack is quite plausibly at a dynamically allocated location, just like `p` in this example - so it then becomes a case of "which was allocated at the higher address", and pretty hopeless to determine reliably.

Comment: @QuinnRoundy: "x64" is MS's way of saying x86-64 - but as MS compilers (at least last time I knew) don't support inline assembler, it makes little difference...

Comment: This link explains very nicely how the stack is organized and a tool is provided for examining the stack. To make it work under Windows x64, you need to replace the inline assembly with some macros. http://rxwen.blogspot.dk/2009/04/detect-stack-corruption.html Google each instruction and you will find the corresponding macros to use

Comment: I translated it to 64-bit, but I left the header at work. I am not using Windows at home :-)

Comment: @Jens That looked like a gcc solution.  In msvc, 64bit, you can't use __asm any longer.

Comment: @johnnycrash. Like I told you. You can easily find macros equivalent to the few asm instructions. It is very simple - I left the header at work and at home I don't have Windows, so I wouldn't start guessing a solution

Comment: To get the return address %edp, %rdp(64-bit), use _AddressOfReturnAddress();

Comment: In addition to the other problems mentioned, what if your smart pointer is ever assigned a member variable of a larger object that was dynamically allocated? It would conclude the variable is not on the stack. But trying to deallocate it would be completely wrong.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish.  I don't exactly understand your comment.

Comment: @Quinn: One reason is for detecting if you need to free an object without adding a property like m_fWasAllocated to the object.

Comment: @Mats.  Where is the stack?  I only see it located in low memory.  It seems to reside right after the executable.  Is the stack simply allocated with malloc when the app starts, and that is the location it gets?  this makes sense since I think I remember that memory allocated with malloc seems to come after the application.  Note, all our memory is allocated with an address above 16 GB, since we have our own memory allocator.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this will get longer than a "comments" worth.

First of all "knowing if you need to free or not" should probably be solved with `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`, not by "checking if it's on the stack or not". What about:

```
void Function(int *p)
{
    if (!isOnStack(p)) delete p;
}


std::vector<int> v;

... fill stuff into v ... 
Function(&v[14]);
```

Freeing in the middle of the `std::vector` is almost certainly a very bad thing - but I guarantee the address is not on the stack.

```
static int x;
Function(&x);
```

no better there - it will also cause bad free.

As to "where the stack is located" is entirely based on the runtime environment (combination of OS and compiler, etc). It may be a high address. It may be a high address in the "main" thread, and a lower address in a secondary thread - but you don't REALLY want this to only work in the "main" thread, do you?

The location of thread's stacks is of course ALSO entirely dependent on the OS and runtime library that provides the thread (and the stack allocation).

You MAY be able to do something like:

```
uintptr_t sp_base;

bool isInStack(void *p)
{
    int x;
    uintptr_t sp_top = (uintptr_t)(&x);
    // Assumes stack grows towards 0.
    return (p > sp_top) && (p < sp_base);
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    sp_base = (uintptr_t)(&x); 
    ... 
}
```

But it far from guaranteed to work every time, or even most of the time - depending on the actual OS and compiler choice, the result may vary quite wildly.

Comment: Thanks.  We use only the visual studio compiler and only run on windows.  our software is internal use only.  The functionality related to memory management is isolated in a few classes, so we could port easily if we wanted to.  Performance is paramount, so everything is custom.  We don't use the standard libraries.  64 bit compiled code appears to locate stack low in memory, right after the exe image.  The heap returns addresses right after the stack.  My guess is threads allocate their stack on the heap, which is in the same low memory location.